# MobileFirst application not using deployed adapter, attempting to use development server adapter instead

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm running MobileFirst 7.0 on a Liberty installation.

Having successfully deployed my application and adapter into the runtime, the preview, when run from the servers operations console, is apparently trying to communicate with the adapter from the development server rather than the one running on Liberty.

```
[/MaximoMobile/apps/services/api/PhyCount/common/query] failure. state: 404, response: undefined
```

The runtime on the server is not called MaximoMobile, that is just the name of the project within Eclipse. It shouldn't be being referenced at all outside of the local copy of Mobilefirst.

I've looked up documentation in instructing the application to use the deployment server rather than the development server using JNDI entries in the server.xml file (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/t_using_JNDI_lookup_to_override_WL_properties.html), but I can't see anything incorrectly set, or anything even relating to the adapter.

I have managed to set the endpoint to /worklight as required using Eclipse, but it's still returning 404 and attempting to access a non-existent file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question for people who may later stumble upon this looking for an answer:

The preview on the server doesn't work in the same way as the local preview does, and any part of the interface that requires an adapter won't function.

If you need to test the connection to the server, deploying to a device will allow you to do so!